# Tornado [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, tornado

We are running a Tornado 3.0 service on a RedHat OS and getting the following error:

```
[E 140102 17:07:37 ioloop:660] Exception in I/O handler for fd 11
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 653, in start
        self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 241, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 136, in accept_handler
        connection, address = sock.accept()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

But we couldn't figure out what that means.

Our Tornado code is as follows:

```
import sys
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.options import parse_command_line, define, options
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.netutil import bind_sockets
import tornado
sys.path.append("..")

from tornado.web import  RequestHandler, Application
from shared.bootstrap import *
from time import time
from clients import ClientFactory

from shared.configuration   import Config
from shared.logger          import Logger

from algorithms.neighborhood.application import NeighborhoodApplication
import traceback

define('port', default=8000, help="Run on the given port", type=int)
define('debug', default=True, help="Run application in debug mode", type=bool)

class WService(RequestHandler):

    _clients = {}

    def prepare(self):
        self._start_time = time()
        RequestHandler.prepare(self)

    def get(self, algorithm = None):

        self.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')

        response = {'skus' : []}

        algorithm = 'neighborhood' if not algorithm else algorithm

        try:
            if not algorithm in self._clients:
                self._clients[algorithm] = ClientFactory.get_instance(algorithm)

            arguments = self.get_arguments_by_client(self._clients[algorithm].get_expected_arguments())

            response['skus'] = app.get_manager().make_recommendations(arguments)
            self.write(response)

        except Exception as err:
            self.write(response)
            error("Erro: " + str(err))

    def get_arguments_by_client(self, expected_arguments):
        arguments = {}
        for key in expected_arguments:
            arguments[key] = self.get_argument(key, expected_arguments[key])

        return arguments

    def on_connection_close(self):
        self.finish({'skus':[]})
        RequestHandler.on_connection_close(self)

    def on_finish(self):
        response_time = 1000.0 *(time() - self._start_time)
        log("%d %s %.2fms" % (self.get_status(), self._request_summary(), response_time))
        RequestHandler.on_finish(self)

def handling_exception(signal, frame):
    error('IOLoop blocked for %s seconds in\n%s\n\n' % ( io_loop._blocking_signal_threshold, ''.join(traceback.format_stack(frame)[-3:])))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    configuration = Config()
    Logger.configure(configuration.get_configs('logger'))

    app = NeighborhoodApplication({
                                   'application': configuration.get_configs('neighborhood'),
                                   'couchbase':   configuration.get_configs('couchbase'),
                                   'stock':       configuration.get_configs('stock')
                                   })
    app.run()
    log("Neighborhood Matrices successfully created...")
    log("Initiating Tornado Service...")

    parse_command_line()

    application = Application([
                               (r'/(favicon.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./images/"}),
                               (r"/(.*)", WService)
                               ], **{'debug':options.debug, 'x-headers' : True})

    sockets = bind_sockets(options.port, backlog=1024)
    server = HTTPServer(application)
    server.add_sockets(sockets)

    io_loop = IOLoop.instance()
    io_loop.set_blocking_signal_threshold(.05, handling_exception)
    io_loop.start()
```

It's a very basic script, basically it gets the URL, process it in the `make_recommendation` function and sends back the response.

We've tried to set a tornado timeout of 50 ms through the `io_loop.set_blocking_signal_threshold` function as sometimes the processing of the URL might take this long.

The system receives around 8000 requests per minute and it worked fine for about 30 minutes, but after that it started throwing the "too many files error" and broke down. On general the requests were taking about 20 ms to get processed but when the error started happening the time consumed increased to seconds, all of a sudden.

We tried to see how many connections the port 8000 had and it had several open connections all with the "ESTABLISHED" status.

Is there something wrong in our Tornado script? We believe our timeout function is not working properly, but for what we've researched so far everything seems to be ok.

If you need more info please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @CDspace
We read it already but couldn't assimilate the answer with our scenario. It looks like something else is missing in our implementation

Comment: just to point this out the question is not a duplicate. Ben's answer is what solved this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many linux distributions ship with very low limits (e.g. 250) for the number of open files per process.  You can use "ulimit -n" to see the current value on your system (be sure to issue this command in the same environment that your tornado server runs as).  To raise the limit you can use the ulimit command or modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` (try setting it to 50000).

Tornado's HTTP server does not (as of version 3.2) close connections that a web browser has left open, so idle connections may accumulate over time.  This is one reason why it is recommended to use a proxy like nginx or haproxy in front of a Tornado server; these servers are more hardened against this and other potential DoS issues.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer, we will try to set a nginx to see how it goes. As the idle connections issue, shouldn't the timeout of 50 ms we set in our implementation handle those already?

Comment: No, idle connections are kept alive without blocking the IOLoop (that is after all kind of the point), so the blocking threshold doesn't apply here.

Comment: I see. Is there some way of closing those idle connections using just Tornado itself? Using nginx as the solution is fine, we were just wondering if we could solve this issue via Tornado.

Comment: You can turn off connection reuse completely by passing no_keep_alive=True to the HTTPServer constructor (or Application.listen)

Comment: Hi Ben, we just did a test by setting `no_keep_alive = True` in `server = HTTPServer(application, no_keep_alive = True)` without the nginx for now and this time our system was up for about one hour and a half (we have two virtual machines, each with its own Tornado service and a load balancer managing the requests) but after that period the time consumed started increasing and we had to turn it off. Is there some other setup in Tornado we are missing? Is there some timeout we can setup so that we avoid some sort of dead connecting taking all of Tornado's resources?

Comment: We have in our code some processing of the URL that involves numpy processing in the line `response['skus'] = app.get_manager().make_recommendations(arguments)`. Is there some way to set Tornado so that if this code takes certain amount of time (say 50 ms) then Tornado closes it and sends a default response? Is it possible? Or is is possible that something is going bad in that line making the request getting stuck and hindering other following requests? Can we "protect" our code somehow so that to avoid the system breaking down?

Comment: There shouldn't be any memory used by these closed connections (although no_keep_alive is not well tested); do you have evidence (e.g. heap profiles) that it's related?

Comment: There's no clean way to ensure that code doesn't run for more than 50ms without that code's cooperation (short of running it in a separate process and killing it if it runs too long).  You could run it on a separate thread so the main thread is still able to return a result to the user, but preventing the system from being overloaded is up to you.

Comment: took me quite a while to reply this issue but thanks Ben for your answer. We set up a Nginx in front of Tornado and the problem was solved.

Comment: What should be changed in limits.conf? Can't see there 1024 or the phrase 'connections'.

Comment: You have to add a line (or two) to limits.conf to increase the `nofile` limit. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-can-i-increase-open-files-limit-for-all-processes/8949