# python: IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files (but there's only one file)

Tags: python, io, ioerror

I am trying to open a file, write into it, and close it with this method which is actually called every second with tornado.ioloop:

```
def save_good_proxies():
    """Save good proxies"""
    global PROXIES
    out_file = open('proxies/good_proxies', 'w')
    for proxy in PROXIES:
        out_file.write(proxy['host'] + ':' + str(proxy['port']) + '\n')
    out_file.close()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), save_good_proxies)
```

After about ten seconds, I receive this error:

> IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Why is this happening if there is only file which is being closed before each time it is opened? Thanks!

Here is the traceback (I modified the code above to simplify and suit the question):

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x10458bc00>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 604, in _run_callback
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
  File "proxies/proxy_checker_walmart2.py", line 38, in test_proxies
  File "proxies/proxy_checker_walmart2.py", line 62, in save_good_proxies
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'proxies/good_proxies'
```

Comment: How are you running this code? In a thread or a process?

Comment: Thanks for the question. This is being run repeatedly by tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current(). I updated the code as well

Comment: Can you show traceback info as well?

Comment: It's added - the code above is modified to suit the question so it won't correlate perfectly with the traceback. From the traceback, it almost looks like out_file.close() is NOT being invoked.

Comment: Besides the point, you should use a context manager like `with open(..) as out_file`. Anyway, could it be that you indeed have too many open files? Check `ulimit -a` and try raising the limit.

Comment: It might be that the file is actually not closed at the time you invoke `open(...)` the second time. Add a check for seeing whether the given file is already opened at the time you call `open(...)` and tell us what you get. And yes, @user2722968 is right - using `with open(...):` is less prone to errors than manually handling the closing and opening.

Comment: I have tried with `with open(..)` but that made no difference. I also made out_file a global variable and added a check to see if it open or closed. Indeed - it is always closed after calling close() and remains open when the call to close() is removed. Very strange.

Comment: For me it looks like the problem is connected to tornado: maybe, these answers will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894133/tornado-errno-24-too-many-open-files?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204685/tornado-error-errno-24-too-many-open-files-error